# Merge/combine values for same observation in R or SAS

Tags: r, sas

A data sets looks like this:

```
name    amt
lucy    100
mark    234
andy    456
wendy   456
lucy    34
wendy   345
```

How to make it in the form below by using R or SAS?

```
name    amt
lucy    134
mark    234
andy    456
wendy   801
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, we can do this with a number of options.  The `base R` includes `aggregate`

```
aggregate(amt~name, df, sum)
```

Or `xtabs`

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(amt~name, df))
```

---

Or with packages like `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(amt = sum(amt))
```

---

Or  `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(amt = sum(amt)), by = name]
```